# Error with rename functions into a list on r

Tags: r, dplyr

My data:

```
library(tidyverse)

1:6%>%
  str_c('var',.)%>%
  map(~assign(.,runif(30,20,100),envir=globalenv()))
tibble<-as_tibble(
  bind_cols(mget(ls(pattern='*v')))
)
cluster<-kmeans(tibble,centers=3)
cluster
tibble$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])
head(tibble)
```

When apply this function, the result it's ok:

```
names(tibble)[str_which(names(tibble),regex('KMEaNS',ignore_case=TRUE))]<-'variable'
```

`variable` is the new name.

For a `list`, this function doesn't work:

```
mylist<-list(dataset1=c(a=1,kmeans=2,c=3),
         dataset2=c(a=4,kmeans=5,c=6),
         dataset2=c(r=7,kmeans=8,p=9))
```

First function:

```
mylist%>%
  lapply(function(x){
    lapply(x,names(x)[str_which(names(x),regex('KMEa',ignore_case=T))])<- 'variable'
})
```

> Error in lapply(x, names(x)[str_which(names(x), regex("KMEa", ignore_case = T))]) <- "variable" : could not find function "lapply<-"

Second function:

```
mylist%>%
  map(.,~names(.)[str_which(names(.),regex('KM',ignore_case=T))])<-'variable'
```

> Error in mylist %>% map(., ~names(.)[str_which(names(.), regex("KM", ignore_case = T))]) <- "variable" : could not find function "%>%<-"

**Two questions**:

- What is the problem with these functions?
- There is a solution with `dplyr::rename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in `mylist` are numeric vector whereas for `rename_at` to work we need a tibble objects. So first we need to convert that numeric vector to tibble object and then we can use `map` and `rename_at` together.

```
library(tidyverse)

mylist[] <- lapply(mylist, function(x) as.tibble(t(x)))
map(mylist, ~ rename_at(., vars(contains('kmeans')), ~ 'variable'))


#$dataset1
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#      a variable     c
#  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1        2     3

#$dataset2
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#      a variable     c
#  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4        5     6

#$dataset2
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#      r variable     p
#  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     7        8     9
```

Answer (score 1):

in function you should return x after renaming to get desired result -

```
mylist<-list(dataset1=c(a=1,kmeans=2,c=3),
             dataset2=c(a=4,kmeans=5,c=6),
             dataset2=c(r=7,kmeans=8,p=9))

fn <- function(x) {names(x)[str_which(names(x),regex('KMEa',ignore_case=T))] <- 'variable'
                  return(x)}
lapply(mylist,fn)
```

or

```
mylist %>% lapply( function(x) {names(x)[str_which(names(x),regex('KMEa',ignore_case=T))] <- 'variable'
return(x)})
```